# AxiosError: Network Error Only on Android, iOS/Postman no error

Tags: android, react-native, axios

I have been struggling for almost three days with an annoying error in React Native. I am attempting to call an ERP API from Dynamics 365 using baseAuth and Axios.

Everything works fine on Postman or iOS, and I receive the data successfully. However, on Android, I only receive...
[AxiosError: Network Error]

```
axios
 .post(
 'https://my.domain.com:58048',
 {
     tableName: 'Item',
     pKValue: '5100/21',
     filterFields: '',
     filterValues: '',
     fieldsToRetrieve: 'Description',
     selectLatestVersion: 'false',
 },
 {
 headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             Company: 'company',
             Authorization: `Basic ${base64encode('user:pass')}`,
         },
     }
 )
```

I tried to:

1. Use rn-fetch-blob
2. Ignore SSL for react native: https://medium.com/@rushitjivani/how-to-ignore-ssl-for-react-native-android-ios-4942e10ea667
3. Add <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in AndroidManifest.xml
4. Create a network_security_config.xml file

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">my.domain.com:58048</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and add <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" in AndroidManifest.xml

The domain has a valid ssl certificate. I don't really know what the problem could be... does anyone know? Thanks!